Why is an array variable not getting updated unless assigning to [:]?
I was solving this leetcode problem of rotating the array right by k places and this is the function I wrote in Python:
class Solution:
    def rotate(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> None:
        n = len(nums)
        k = k % n
        nums[:n - k] = nums[:n - k][::-1]
        nums[n - k:] = nums[n - k:][::-1]
        nums = nums[::-1]

Now the problem is that when the nums array is printed finally, it's printing the value stored after line no. 6 and not line no. 7. But when I change line no. 7 to nums[:] = nums[::-1], it prints the correct solution. I can't understand why.

Remember that you're not passing names, you're passing objects.  When you say nums = nums[::-1], that creates a brand-new object that is not related to the one that is passed in, which then gets discarded.  You might try nums[] = nums[::-1].

@TimRoberts I believe that needs to be nums[:] = nums[::-1].  You need to use slicing notation on the left.
